# What are usually the basis on grouping Fargate applications under an ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Based on amazon docs:

> An Amazon ECS cluster is a logical grouping of tasks or services. If you are running tasks or services that use the EC2 launch type, a cluster is also a grouping of container instances. If you are using capacity providers, a cluster is also a logical grouping of capacity providers. When you first use Amazon ECS, a default cluster is created for you, but you can create multiple clusters in an account to keep your resources separate.

In our use case, we are not using EC2 launch types. We are mainly using Fargate.

What are the usual basis/strategy on grouping services? Is it a purely subjective thing?

Lets say I have a Payment Service, Invoice/Receipt Service, User Service, and Authentication Service. Do I put some of them in an ECS cluster or is it best practice to have them on separate ECS clusters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A service is a functioning application, so for example you might have an authentication service or payment service etc.

Whilst services can speak between one another, a service by itself should contain all parts to make it work, these parts are the containers.

Your service may be as simple as one container, or contain many containers to provide its functionality such as caching or background jobs.

The services concept generally comes from the ideas of both [service driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) and [micro service architecture](https://microservices.io/).

Ultimately the decision comes down to you, you could put everything under one service, but this could lead to problems further down the line.

One key point to note is the scaling of containers is done at a service levels so you would need to increase all containers that are part of your task definition. You generally want to scale to meet the demands of functionality.

An ECS Cluster may contain one service or contain a number of services that produce a deliverable. For example in AWS S3 is made up of more than 200 micro services, these would be a cluster. However you would not expect every AWS service to be part of the same cluster.

In your scenario you define several services, personally I would separate these into different clusters as they deliver completely different business functions.

Comment: I might have explained my question poorly. I understand what you mentioned, my question is specific to the ECS Cluster feature of AWS. It groups multiple services. Assuming I have multiple services/applications, how do people usually decide if they put them in one ECS Cluster or not..

Comment: Added to the bottom of the answer, let me know if you want any further informaiton

Comment: Would you say grouping by business function or product makes sense? Like for example, cluster all accounting related services? One hesitation I have is having 1:1 with service:cluster, and ending up with too granular clustering. So I'm exploring ideas on how others do it.

Comment: I'd say it tends to reflect on your business model and the services stakeholders.I could see all accounting related services sitting in a cluster. :)

Comment: I have one more detail question. Are there any technical limitations (e.g. inter service comms) if I create a separate cluster for each service as opposed to a cluster for all services?

Comment: There aren't technical limitations (they can all talk to each other) as long as your security groups and NACLs allow for it

Answer (score 0):

I've been considering the same question myself, and I've come to the conclusion that you (we) can generally take one of two approaches:

- **Cluster per service** - each of your clusters contains all versions of a given service, e.g. `service-test`, `service-qa`, `service-production`.
- **Cluster per environment** - each cluster contains all services required to run a given application environment. In this case, you'd have a cluster named something like `accounts` with multiple services inside such as `accounts-test`, `accounts-production`, etc.

I'm sure there are other options out there, but these two seem to make the best sense to me. And I tend to lean toward the second option.

Comment: If you extend this logic with the AWS multi-account strategy where you have a separate AWS account for each environment, the option becomes cluster per account. This is usually the approach that I've gone for in the past when architecting micro-service applications.